# Проблема - Unable to connect to any of the specified mySQL host - странность с паролем

Tags: mysql, terminal

Удалил полностью mySQL v5.5.29 (каталоги тоже, БД тоже).
Ставлю заново (второй день, 120-ая попытка). В основном спотыкается на применении политик безопасности.
Но странно, через Navicat подключаюсь без пароля, хотя в установке нельзя оставить пароль пустым (я там ставлю пароль).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вход через Navicat, хост localhost, пользователь root, пароль пустой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя через консоль без пароля не входит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это за проблема и как её исправить?
MySQLInstanceConfig.exe тоже не помог, пытался через него сменить пароль - зависает на применении политик безопасности.

**P.S. Кстати, через mySQL Workbench тоже захожу. Может через них (Navicat, Workbench) как-то сменить пароль можно?**

Answer (score 0):

Как всё оказалось примитивно просто.
Сменил пароль стандартно-указанным пользователям (root@*) данному соединению через Navicat и всё.
Установка mySQL не знаю, как ведёт себя теперь и почему не принимала пароль из установки, который я вводил, ведь БД не было и даже каталогов(!), но нет времени проверять\выяснять причины. Главное пока что для меня то, что ПО заработало (нужна его доработка).
Я ранее в Navicat там пароль менял, но с последующей переустановкой - не помогало.
Поэтому думаю проблема может вылезти где-то, когда-то позже. Опять же при переустановки СУБД.